# Magento 2 search result sort order changes(shuffles) every time result page is refreshed

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, solr

We have a Magento2 EE configured with Solr and Manadev layered navigation extension. When we perform a search:

- Search result yields correct and as expected result
- Result is displayed and sorted by Relevance (e.g  1. A, 2. B, 3. C, 4. D)
- Up to this point, there is nothing unexpected.All good.
- Now, we just refresh the page ( No changes made anywhere at all)
- Result and count is same but with different order (1. B, 2. D, 3. A, 4.C)

This is strange. Which one is culprit here ? Magento EE itself or Manadev Extension or Solr ?

FYI, not matter how many searches we make directly on solr console with the same query string, result ORDER(sorting) remains the same. This makes solr end somewhat non suspicious.

Has anyone faced this issue before ?

Any hint for this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to conflict between Search Result and Amasty Sorting module.

Amasty Sorting module extends available search filters on products list and search result pages.

Amasty has mentioned on their documentation that it doesn't support solr but not sure why.